# created_at field date update when call save() method

Tags: node.js, knex.js, adonis.js, lucid

When I update the status field in destroy then update created_at field date.
this is my controller code

```
 async destroy({ params, request, response }) {
    try {
      const Applicationdata = await Application.find(params.id)
      if (Applicationdata) {
        Applicationdata.status = !Applicationdata.status
        await Applicationdata.save()
        return response.ok(Config.get('HttpResponse.OK'), {
              Applicationdata
        })
      } else {
        return response.fail(
          Config.get('HttpResponse.NOT_FOUND'),
          Antl.formatMessage('messages.recordNotFound')
        )
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return response.fail(
        Config.get('HttpResponse.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR'),
        Antl.formatMessage('messages.serverError')
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Applicationdata.status = !Applicationdata.status what you are doing here ?

Comment: I am toggle status if the status is active then change to deactivate and deactivate then the active status

Comment: are you getting success response or error response after api call

Comment: no problem in response I get back  success after call this

Comment: and status get updated too. right .but created_date not am i right ??

Comment: when i update status then created_at date also update.

Comment: i think i get your problem. just add your Applicationdata modal as well and let me check .

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce your problem. Can you share your models and migrations (or the project). What db do you use?